# Are there differences between ReactJS v0.13.3 and v0.14.0?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Started to look at `ReactJS` and noticed that the latest version of `ReactTS` (typescript) `0.13.3`, and the `ReactJS` version `0.14.0`.

Question - are there any differences between versions `0.13.3` and `0.14.0`?
Is it possible to join without restrictions `ReactJS V0.14.0` + `ReactTS V0.13.3`?

Comment: You can read about the changes in React v0.14 [in the release blog post](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html). Not sure about TypeScript.

Comment: If your code is react-warning free, you should be ok, aside of a bunch of deprecations (follow the migration guide @FelixKling just shared) - you will  have to upgrade some modules that are not compatible anymore (their API may have changed in the way - this is what will take you most of your time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a big changes in 0.14. Main change is splitting code base into two packages: main react part and react dom library, so looks like it's impossible to make these different versions working together.

You can read all changes [here](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html)